# Facebook page design is not working in IE8

Tags: css, facebook, internet-explorer-8

We have designed a face book page.It is working fine in all browser including IE7 but it is not working in IE8.We checked then we got if we run our code outside the face book page it works in IE8 but when we put our code into face book page its not working.Here is the css code what we are using for IE8.

```
 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.nv_a
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
        padding-top:8px;    
}

.nvt_a
{
    width:66px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
        padding-top:8px;    
}

.nv_a a
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    border-top:solid 1px #999;
    border-left:solid 1px #999;
    border-right:solid 1px #999;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #999;
}

.nv_a a:hover
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    padding-top:8px;
    float:left;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.nvt_a a
{
    width:66px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    border-top:solid 1px #999;
    border-left:solid 1px #999;
    border-right:solid 1px #999;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #999;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Please help us to solve the issue.

Comment: Please prettify the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only targets IE with version less than IE8...

This line, before your style element, says: `<!--[if lt IE 8]>`. This basically means:

- If the IE browser version is less than (`lt`) IE 8, then include the style declarations within this comment.

Now, since your question is a bit vague, you either want to target all versions of IE up to and including IE 8, OR you just want to target IE 8:

- Target all versions up-to-and-including IE8: `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`
- Target ONLY IE 8: `<!--[if IE 8]>`

Comment: so what i have to write ?Please suggest.

Comment: Updated to give a better explanation.